# How would one calculate Pi using Fixed-Point Arithmetic using the leibniz series?

Tags: pi, fixed-point, integer-arithmetic, alu

I am trying to use an ALU and Leibniz Series to approximate pi using only integer operations ie multiplication and shifting. Does anyone know how I could program this in C?

Comment: Depending on what the purpose of this exercise is, use of a [*spigot algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm) may be a good choice. As far as I know, the algorithms are not based on the Leibniz formula for π, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  sum = sum + (-1) * (1 / (2.0 * i + 1));
}

Printf("Pi=%f",4 * (sum + 1));
```

Comment: would this not be lost to integer division truncation?

Comment: With the promotion to `double`, I don't think that qualifies as "using only integer operations".